# How to access the PID from an lsof.

Tags: bash, terminal

Given the following command `lsof -i:1025` I get:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12345 john   11u  IPv4 0xb2f4161230e18fd57      0t0  TCP localhost:foobar (LISTEN)
```

I am trying to write a script to get that PID (12345) and kill it. At the moment I have to run `lsof -i:1025`, get that PID and then run `kill -9 12345`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash --

x=`lsof -Fp -i:1025`
kill -9 ${x##p}
```

Should do it. The 3rd line runs `lsof` using the `-F` option to get just the pid, with a leading `p`. The next line drops the leading p from the output of `lsof` and uses the result as the pid in a `kill` command.

Edit: At some point `lsof` was modified so the file descriptor preceded by an `f` is always output, whether you ask for it or not (which makes no sense to me, but what do I know). While you could put a `| grep '^p'` in the back quotes, an easier way is to use the `-t` option, as noted in fabianopinto's answer below.

Comment: What is the `${x##p}` syntax ?

Comment: I get an error: `kill: illegal pid: 13013\nf22`

Comment: @CobyBugstein `${x##p}` is bash's pattern matching parameter expansion syntax. It matches the pattern `p` in `$x` and deletes the longest occurrence of it. In this case it matches the `p` at the start of the line and deletes it. On your other question, that's due to a change to `lsof` since I wrote my answer. I'll edit my answer to note that.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work as well with only one `#` btw

Answer (score 55):

The [lsof(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) man page says:

```
   -t       specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process
            identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output
            may be piped to kill(1).  -t selects the -w option.
```

You can use `lsof -t -i:1025 | xargs kill -9`.

Comment: worked like charm! `lsof -ti:1025` also works.

Answer (score 4):

This shortcut will kill the process quickly for you

```bash
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :3000)
```

for fish shell users, simply remove the $ sign, so

```bash
kill -9 (lsof -t -i :3000)
```

Comment: Great! Could not find listening-port with `netstat`, but with `lsof`.

Answer (score 3):

Further to [@blm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33615913/863110), it didn't work for me exactly because the output of the `lsof` command was:

```
p4679
f33
```

So with the `${x##p}` was

```
4679
f33
```

**The solution**

Grab only the [first line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46021955/863110) with `| head -n 1`:

```sh
x=`lsof -Fp -i:"$1" | head -n 1`
kill -9 ${x##p}
```

Comment: Yes, `lsof` was changed at some point after I wrote my answer to always include the file descriptor on a line starting with `f`, whether you asked for it or not. I've updated my answer to note that.

Answer (score 2):

`man lsof` says that you can use `-F` to specify fields to to be output for processing by other programs. So you can do something like

```
lsof -i:1025 -Fp | sed 's/^p//' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 2):

And furthermore from @blm's and @Mosh Feu's answers:

```
lsof -i:1337 -Fp | head -n 1 | sed 's/^p//' | xargs kill
```

is what ended up doing the trick for me.

I recommend adding this as a bash function and aliasing it

```
alias kbp='killByPort'
killByPort() {
  lsof -i:$1 -Fp | head -n 1 | sed 's/^p//' | xargs kill
}
```